# Android In-App purchase Google checkout

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-checkout

I am considering to do an in-app purchase model within a paid app that releases or adds video content if the user opts in via a google check out method. Does anyone know how to do this from a coding standpoint? and does anyone know if this is possible?

thank you ahead of time...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible do in-app purchases with Google's new In-App Billing services, see the documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html

However, note that In-App Billing relies on the [2.3 version of the Android Market](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_about.html) .

> NOTE: Old version of my answer, before
>   In-App billing was announced
>
> Unfortunately, there are not official
>   mechanisms to do micropayments on
>   Android apps distributed via the
>   Android Market yet. You also are not
>   allowed to implement your own methods
>   according to the [Android Market
>   Developer Agreement](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_about.html):
>
> > All fees received by Developers for
> >     Products distributed via the Market
> >     must be processed by the Market's
> >     Payment Processor
>
> Google offers no API to handle
>   payments, and all payments must be
>   handled by  the Market's Payment
>   Processor, so it's catch 22.
>
> [1](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_about.html):
>   http://www.android.com/us/developer-distribution-agreement.html

Comment: AndDev tutorial is very easy and to understand what Google is saying is very difficult.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2/2/11, Google announced it's releasing in-app purchase for Android apps. The SDK is now available while the in-app purchase will be "live to users prior to the end of this quarter." (Q1/2011)

Comment: where did you find this info?